# Ajax call blocking other javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I am using **flex slider** on a page and page also making an **ajax call** for other job. My issue is when user load the page, **ajax call** block **flex slider** until ajax request has not been completed. After completed ajax request, flex slider loaded  successfully. If i remove ajax script then flex slider is loading very fast.

Flex slider and ajax request both are written between this code...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#carousel').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: true,
        animationLoop: true,
        slideshow: false,
        itemWidth: 100,
        itemMargin: 15,        
        asNavFor: '#slider'        
    });

    // Rest code of slider will come here

    // Ajax code start from here    
    $.ajax({ 
            type: "GET",
            async:false,
            url: prefixUrl, 
            success: function(results) { 
                    $(results).insertBefore('.event_container'); 
            }
        });

});
```

Please suggest any ideas so that ajax call should not block flex slider.

Thank you

Comment: Don't set async to false if you don't want it to block.

Comment: @kinakuta# Also not working after changing async:true

Comment: No error in console

Comment: You say "not working" ... what DOES happen, what do you EXPECT instead

Comment: "not working" means same happening

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Async false will wait till your operation get complete.

try this :

```
$.ajax({ 
        type: "GET",
        async:true,
        url: prefixUrl, 
        success: function(results) { 
                $(results).insertBefore('.event_container'); 
        }
    });
```

//update 2 :

Actually it is happening since you have added Ajax in ready function so till your ajax is running page ready event is not getting completed. try removing it from document ready.

Comment: I have added new comments please try that..hope that will solve your issue

Comment: Ya # After using async:true, it's working but ajax is not giving proper response means async:false giving 6 column results but async:true, giving 3 columns result. Can you suggest how to handle this?

Comment: Your ajax have any dependancy?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this..i am not able get your problem completely

Comment: async: false is okay but async: true is not giving response in sequence http://jsfiddle.net/anilk1797/y7yhd/49/
I want same result but using async: true.

Comment: See since you are using ajax in loop...async false will wait till response come then will go for next iteration of loop..while async true wont wait and loop will keep executing thats y you are getting result in such a way....now please tell me what is your expected results...i will create a new fiddle for you :)

Comment: I want same result like async: false but using async: true because async:false block the other events while request is not completed

Comment: Thank you! this is the same what i need http://stackoverflow.com/a/19332078/2756584

Answer (score 0):

We use ajax for not getting post-back operation and in your code you mentioned like async: false which leads to synchronous ajax call. Synchronous ajax call makes you to stop/block until you get the response for the previous request. So try this:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    url: yourURL, 
    success: function(results) { 
            $(results).insertBefore('.event_container'); 
    },
    async:true
});
```

Comment: Changing async:true working fast but again flex slider loads after ajax request complete. 
Is there any other option so that flex slider and ajax call don't depends on each other?